# Verificar si elemento de un array se encuentra en otro array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo 2 array uno que tiene "Productos" y otro que tiene "productosExcluidos".

tengo que excluir los productos que estén en el array "productosExcluidos" del listado final "Productos" que se muestra en un `<option>`

```
for(let i=0;i<$scope.productos.length;i++){
         
    $('#select-servicio').append($('<option value='+ $scope.productos[i].idProducto +' >' + $scope.productos[i].descripcion + '</option>'));
  
}
```

Mi idea era recorrerlos con 2 for anidados, pero el array tiene mas de 100.000 valores, por lo que va a ser super ineficiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Qué tal?

Haciendo el uso de `includes()`, `filter` y `spread operator`, puede lograr el filtro, uniendo los productos para mostrarse en un select de la siguiente forma:

**HTML**

```
<select id="select">
   <option selected="selected">Productos</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
let productos = ['uno','dos','tres','cuatro']
let excluidos = ['dos', 'cuatro','cinco','nueve']

let options = document.getElementById('select');

let filtro = [...productos,...excluidos.filter(p=> !productos.includes(p))]
filtro.forEach(items => {
  options.add(new Option(`${items}`));
});
```

Spreat operator convierte 2 arrays en uno nuevo con los valores que filter() se encarga de retornar, junto con includes(), que verifica que el array excluidos retorne productos que no estén en el array productos para generar el nuevo array. Luego solo se iteran los resultados insertándolos en el `select>`

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el método `includes()` dentro del for así solo tendrás uno, de la siguiente manera

```
let myarray1 = ['hola','este','es','el','array','del','ciclo','for']
let myarray2 = ['lo', 'que','quieres','comparar','es']
for(let i=0;i<myarray1.length;i++){
    let element = myarray1[i]
    if(myarray2.includes(element)){
        console.log(`coincide '${element}'`)
    }
}
```

en la parte del `console.log(${element})` lo puedes sustituir por un codigo que quite los productos excluidos del array productos

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta podría solucionar el problema, es recomendable siempre darle un ejemplo a OP explicándole como funciona para que comprenda la solución que propones. ;)

Comment: Pero como seria algo como,`myArray.includes(myArra2)` ? o como?

Comment: listo, ya agregue un ejemplo